# How to count the number of comparisons happening when organizing an array?

Tags: java, arrays

I have this java code that sorts a set of random scores. What I need to do is modify sortArray so that it returns the total number of comparisons that were made during its calls to findMinLoc and modify the main to call the modiﬁed sortArray correctly, capturing the number of comparisons total into a variable. I am very new to programming and I'm having a complete block on how to do this. I've attempted to use a counter however it always displays only the amount of scores not how many comparisons were made to put the array in order.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Lab11 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);
        final int Size = 10; 
        double [] scores = new double[Size];
        // set all the scores to a random number [0 - 99] 
        for (int s = 0; s < Size; ++s)
            scores[s] = (int)(Math.random() * 100);
        // print the scores - original order 
        System.out.println("Scores - Original"); 
        System.out.println("------------------"); 
        printArray(scores, Size); 
        System.out.println("\n");
        // sort the scores 
        System.out.println("Sorting ...\n");
        // print the scores - sorted order 
        sortArray(scores, Size);
        System.out.println("Size of array = " + Size);
        System.out.println("Comparisons needed =   \n");
        System.out.println("Scores - Sorted");
        System.out.println("----------------");
        printArray(scores, Size); 
        System.out.println("\n");
        stdIn.close();
    }
    public static void printArray(double [] arr, int eSize) 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < eSize; ++i) 
            System.out.println(arr[i]); 
    }
    public static int findMinLoc(double [] arr, int startInd, int     endInd) 
    {
        int minLoc = startInd; 
        for (int i = startInd; i <= endInd; ++i)
        { 
            if (arr[i] < arr[minLoc]) 
                minLoc = i; 
        }
        return minLoc;
    }
    public static void swapInArray(double [] arr, int ind1, int ind2)
    { 
        double tmp = arr[ind1]; 
        arr[ind1] = arr[ind2]; 
        arr[ind2] = tmp; 
    }
    public static void sortArray(double [] arr, int eSize) 
    { 
        for (int i = 0; i < eSize; ++i) 
        { 
            int ind = findMinLoc(arr, i, eSize-1); 
            swapInArray(arr, i, ind); 
        }
    }
}
```

It should look something like..
Scores - Original -----------------
69.0 
56.0 
19.0 
70.0 
88.0 
86.0 
56.0 
19.0 
79.0 
20.0
Sorting ...

Size of array = 10 
Comparisions needed = 55

### Scores - Sorted

19.0 
19.0 
20.0 
56.0 
56.0 
69.0 
70.0 
79.0 
86.0 
88.0

each method I tried always came up with the caparisons needed being 10 and I don't understand why. Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

If 55 was the amount of comparisons you were expecting.
Globally define

```
static int minLocComps = 0;
```

and add an increment

```
for (int i = startInd; i <= endInd; ++i)
    { 
        if (arr[i] < arr[minLoc]) 
            minLoc = i; 
        minLocComps++; //<-- Here
    }
```

And finally your print out.

```
System.out.println("Comparisons needed = " + minLocComps +"\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just define static count variable globally and add increment the count in the finfMinLoc function as below:

```
static int count=0;

public static int findMinLoc(double [] arr, int startInd, int endInd) 
    {
        int minLoc = startInd; 
        for (int i = startInd; i <= endInd; ++i)
        { 
            count++;
            if (arr[i] < arr[minLoc]) 
                minLoc = i; 
        }
        return minLoc;
    }
```

And add the count variable in print statement:

```
System.out.println("Comparisons needed =   \n" +count);
```

Answer (score 0):

simply add a counter and place it after the compare:

import java.util.Scanner;

public class tst 
{
  private static int comparisonCount = 0;

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{ 
    Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);
    final int Size = 10; 
    double [] scores = new double[Size];
    // set all the scores to a random number [0 - 99] 
    for (int s = 0; s < Size; ++s)
        scores[s] = (int)(Math.random() * 100);
    // print the scores - original order 
    System.out.println("Scores - Original"); 
    System.out.println("------------------"); 
    printArray(scores, Size); 
    System.out.println("\n");
    // sort the scores 
    System.out.println("Sorting ...\n");
    // print the scores - sorted order 
    sortArray(scores, Size);
    System.out.println("Size of array = " + Size);
    System.out.println("Comparisons needed =   " + comparisonCount + "\n");
    System.out.println("Scores - Sorted");
    System.out.println("----------------");
    printArray(scores, Size); 
    System.out.println("\n");
    stdIn.close();
}
public static void printArray(double [] arr, int eSize) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < eSize; ++i) 
        System.out.println(arr[i]); 
}
public static int findMinLoc(double [] arr, int startInd, int     endInd) 
{
    int minLoc = startInd; 
    for (int i = startInd; i <= endInd; ++i)
    { 
        if (arr[i] < arr[minLoc]) 
            minLoc = i;
        comparisonCount++;
    }
    return minLoc;
}
public static void swapInArray(double [] arr, int ind1, int ind2)
{ 
    double tmp = arr[ind1]; 
    arr[ind1] = arr[ind2]; 
    arr[ind2] = tmp; 
}
public static void sortArray(double [] arr, int eSize) 
{ 
    for (int i = 0; i < eSize; ++i) 
    { 
        int ind = findMinLoc(arr, i, eSize-1); 
        swapInArray(arr, i, ind); 
    }
}
```

}